# BlockCopy C# to java - is there any way to do this

Tags: java

The BlockCopy which can be found under the System namespace in C# has following parameters:

```
public static void BlockCopy(
 Array src,
 int srcOffset,
 Array dst,
 int dstOffset,
 int count
)
```

Is there any implementation in java for this?

I have a Byte-array which contains a file, and I need this function i java. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [`System.arraycopy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29). (It takes the exact same arguments.)

Comment: Thanks. I will accept answer as soon as am allowed to do so :)